# InflateException: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

My application runs fine on API level 18+. But, when I run it on API 18, it crashes with following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{navdrawer.test.com.navigationdrawertest/navdrawer.test.com.navigationdrawertest.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:804)
   (many similar exception lines)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
   at android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:265)
   at android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:294)
   (many similar exception lines)
```

[i'm try on this site](http://truelogic.org/wordpress/2016/04/21/create-a-navigation-drawer-in-android/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SO Rule 1: paste relevant code along with exceptions and errors. Rule 2: Follow Rule1 first. paste your layout file and code.

Comment: Check your `ListView` layout if you have define this attribute `android:entries` then remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Check your relevant xml file where you might use wrong attribute which is not supported in Api 18